# Proving area of two parallelograms equal.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Source: Challenge And Thrill Of Pre College Mathematics

On the line segment $AB$, parallelograms $ABCD$ and $ABXY$ are drawn on opposite sides and $AB$ or $AB$ produced bisects $CX$. Prove that $ABCD$ and $ABXY$ have equal area.

Suppose $AB$ intersects $CX$ at $M$. Then if $\triangle BMC$ can be proven congruent to $\triangle BMX$ then that would mean that their heights are $MC = MX$. I am unable to proceed further from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the line $AB$ bisects the interval $CX$, the perpendiculars dropped from $C$ and from $X$ to the line $AB$ have the same length.  This means that the parallelograms $ABCD$ and $ABXY$ have the same altitude.  Since they have the same base, it follows that the areas are the same.